# XCode 6.0.1 - xmlParseEntityRef: no name on Launch Screen.xib

Tags: xcode, screen, ios8, launch

After adding a Launch Screen on my Project, XCode 6 immediately flags me with

Line 14: xmlParseEntityRef: no name

Everytime I choose the Launch Screen.xib, XCode notifies me of this issue.
I checked and Launch Screen.xib is present on my Bundle Resources.

I wonder what's wrong.

XCode Version 6.0.1
Deployment Target: 7.1
Language: Objective-C

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I just filed a bug report with Apple on this same issue. The default Launch Screen template includes your app's name as a label and if that name has an ampersand it invalidates the XML. You can fix this by opening your Launch Screen in a text editor (right click on it in Xcode and select "Open with External Editor" and then doing a Find & Replace for `&` with `&amp;`.

Comment: Thank you, I've had this error for days.

Apparently, if you're Company Identifier contains an &, (ex Tom & Jerry)you need to do what richrad said.

Comment: FYI: They closed my bug report as a duplicate. I haven't checked out the Xcode 6.1 betas yet but this could already be fixed.

Answer (score 7):

**Open with External Editor** and then doing a **Find and Replace** for `&` with `&amp;` worked for me. I found I needed `&amp;` instead of `&amp` to clear an additional error message

```
Line 14: EntityRef: expecting ';'
```

Thank you.

Comment: This was my issue as my app name has an ampersand in it and the xib auto-generates the title.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, turned out it was an unescaped ampersand in my "text" attribute value of the label element (line 14). Try opening Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.xib in a text editor and looking for invalid XML syntax.

Answer (score 0):

if your project name contains &, you may get 'interface builder xib compile error line 20,entityref :...'  when you build it.

my solution is change my project name and then ,open that launchscreen.xib with 'open with external editor',and then command+f to find where & is, change it.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the XIB launch screen. Problem was solved. I'm not sure if you want to do that, but it worked for me.